# Flutter.h not found' error in Xcode when building Flutter app

Tags: ios, swift, flutter, xcode

I'm encountering a "Flutter.h not found" error when trying to build my Flutter app in Xcode. This error is causing an issue in my PluginRegistrant file, and I've tried several potential solutions - like reinstalling pod files, updating dependencies, and creating a new project - but nothing seems to be working.

It seems like my project is unable to access the Flutter framework, even though my certificates are valid in the keychain. I've made some changes to the podfile in the Pods directory, but that didn't help either.

At this point, I'm not sure what else to do. If you have any suggestions, I'd really appreciate it.

Sometimes its the sqflite, geolocator or permission handler. There are always some packages that are unable to access Flutter.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

i trying many thing then I found a solution!

1.Backup ios/Runner folder.

2.Delete the ios folder.

3.Run flutter create (your project name). in the previous folder where you have your project(cd users/user/"projects_folder") (this will recreate your ios folder).

4.Paste your Runner backup in the ios folder (into the project).

5.Open Runner.xcworkspace (into ios folder) and there, check the Version, the Bundle ID, all the info.

(If do you Have Firebase, you have to copy and paste again the Google Service-Info.Plist into the Runner folder (Always through Xcode) (If do you do this manually, it doesn't work).

Finally, flutter run and should work!

If flutter run fails:

cd ios

pod install

cd ..

flutter run